# How to write if/else statements if dataframe is empty in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do the following:
If there is nothing in the dataframe, print "no_match".

If there is something, bind it to the `ID` of dataframe `df2`:

```
if(df == []){
print("nomatch")
}else{
cbind(df, df2$id2)
}
```

Comment: What do you consider *nothing in the data frame* to be?  No rows?  No columns?  Both?  100% `NA` values?

Comment: The dataframe technically doesn't exist because the data passed through a series of filters, I think this is where the problem is

Comment: `if(exists("df")) ...` can be used to determine if `df` exists in the environment.  If it didn't exist you would be receiving an *object 'df' not found* error in your current code.

Answer (score 38):

You could get the information about the dimensions of your data frame via `dim`. For example running the code:

```
data(mtcars)
dim(mtcars)
```

will show you the dimensions:

```
[1] 32 11
```

For a `NULL` object you would get:

```
mtcars <- NULL
dim(mtcars)
NULL
```

`dim` is quite flexible as in case of a `data.frame` with no rows:

```
mtcars <- mtcars[-c(1:dim(mtcars)[1]),]
```

you will get

```
> dim(mtcars)
[1]  0 11
```

### IF statements

Constructing `if` statements is very simple, depening on what you want to check you can do

#### Object is `NULL`

*The object is `NULL`, no rows **and** no columns.

```
if (dim(df) == NULL) {
}
```

#### No rows

*This data frame has columns but no observations.*

```
if (dim(df)[1] == 0) {

}
```

#### No columns

*The object is still of class `data.frame` but has no data.

```
if (dim(df)[2] == 0) {

}
```

You would construct the object like that (if of interest):

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars <- mtcars[,-c(1:dim(mtcars)[2])]
```

---

Naturally, you can combine conditions to check for both or one event of data frame being *empty*.

Answer (score 16):

It depends, is your `data.frame` actually empty or are all the elements something you consider empty.

If the `data.frame` is empty you can use `nrow` as a simple check.

```
tmp <- data.frame(A = numeric())
nrow(tmp)
[1] 0

if(nrow(tmp) == 0){
    print("data.frame is empty")
}else{
    print("data.frame contains data")
}
```

**EDIT** - OP asks about object existence

You can check if an object has been defined with `exists`

```
exists("tmp2")
[1] FALSE
exists("tmp")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: If the dataframe was a product of a filter which obtained no results than the dataframe would not be empty, it would simply not exist.  Therefore naming the dataframe wouldn't get me the result I want correct?  How do I say if the dataframe doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

Is `max(dim(df)) == 0` doing the trick?

```
if (max(dim(df)) == 0) {
  print("nomatch")
} else {
  cbind(df, df2$id2)
}
```