# R- merging a list of tibbles

Tags: r

I am merging a list of tibbles, 80000 in particular. I think some in there are nulls, or empty dataframes, but I am having problem to flesh them out.

I am using the following code, with no success

```
category_data_non_empty <- Filter(Negate(is.null), category_data_names)
category_data_df <- reduce(function(x ,y) merge(x, y, by=names(x)[1]), category_data_non_empty)
```

what other tidy ways could i do?

Comment: Take a look at [How to write if/else statements if dataframe is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366187/how-to-write-if-else-statements-if-dataframe-is-empty) for some examples that may help.

Comment: *with no success* is not helpful. Please describe errors or undesired results. BTW - base R's `Reduce` is capital case.

Comment: Thank you so much @RussThomas! @Parfait I couldnt provide adivce as R never finished computing my first attempt. I will try adding more info in my future requests. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 2):

And the winner was: Thank you all for the help

```
category_data_non_empty     <- lapply(category_data_names, function(x) !is.null(dim(x))) %>% unlist(use.names = FALSE) # %>% unlist(use.names = FALSE) 

category_data_df            <- category_data_names[category_data_non_empty] %>% bind_rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider `NROW` in `Filter` to remove `NULL` or `NA` elements or empty data frames in list.

```
category_data_non_empty <- Filter(NROW, category_data_names)

category_data_df <- Reduce(function(x ,y) merge(x, y, by=names(x)[1]),
                           category_data_non_empty)
```

Otherwise, your current attempt needs an anonymous function argument passed since you run two nested methods. However, this leaves empty (zero-row) data frames:

```
Filter(function(df) Negate(is.null(df)), category_data_names)
```